# Django admin group by FK

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

How do I go about grouping a set of fields within the Django Admin. By this I mean

Table 1: User 
- User Key
- User Name

Table 2: Post
- Post Key
- User Key (FK)

In the PostAdmin I would like to display the User Name of the Author also perform an action on the blogs. This works but displays the user name for each blog created by the user.

Is there a way I could just display the user name once but in the action update all blogs created by the user?

**Model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(
    _("first name"), max_length=50,
    validators=[RegexValidator(
        regex_alpha, code='invalid_first_name',
        message=regex_alpha_message,
    )]
)
middle_name = models.CharField(
    _("middle name"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None,
    validators=[RegexValidator(
        regex_alpha, code='invalid_middle_name',
        message=regex_alpha_message,
    )]
)

class Post(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=250)
label = models.ForeignKey(Label, verbose_name=_('label'))
significance = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=SIGNIFICANCE_CHOICES)
is_sealed = models.BooleanField(_('Is Sealed?'), default=False)
event_date = models.DateField()
message = models.TextField(_("Message"), blank=True, default='')
```

**PostAdmin** (I need to fix the issue here)

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['owner','is_sealed']
ordering = ['owner']
actions = [open_vault]
search_fields = ['owner__email',]
list_filter = ['owner__email']
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Can't you use a foreign key? Also it would be helpful if you show the models.py.

Comment: please show your models.py

Comment: I have used the FK and it works but say if the user (userA) has published 5 blogs in the admin I see userA listed 5 times. Instead of just one userA. I can post the models later today don't have it with me right now